# Flask: Iterating through a dictionary whose vlaues are lists of tuples

Tags: dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have a dict whose values are lists of tuples.  I want to build a table for every key.

```
mydict = {'Western Division': [(0, 1, 'Oakland'), (0, 2, 'San Jose')], 'Eastern Division': [(1, 1, 'Boston'), (1, 2, 'Buffalo')]}
```

My template is:

```
{% for key, value in mydict %}
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        </tr>
        {% for team in value %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ team[2] }}</td>
            </tr> 
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I tried changing the first for-loop to `for key, value, team`, thinking that I want to call each tuple in each list in each key, but got the same error (expected 3).

Lastly, I tried `for key, value in mydict.items` and got TypeError: 'builtin_function-or_method' object is not iterable.

It's definitely possible that I made a mistake further upstream in creating the dict, but I suspect I am just not building my template correctly.

Comment: can you try: `for key, value in mydict.items()`? i believe Django templates drop the parens/brackets at the end, but i don't think Jinja does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mechanical_meat provided the answer in their comment.  `items` needs parens in jinja2.